# What kind of differential equation is $y'=2(\frac{y+2}{x+y-1})^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation in the form $y'=2(\frac{y+2}{x+y-1})^2$. Does this type of equation have a name? I'm struggling to find any information about it or the solution method. My book says this can be solved similarly to the equation $y'=\frac{y+2}{x+y-1}$. That is, with substitutions we can turn this into a homogenous equation and then separate the variables. However, since the expression is inside a function this makes things difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Rewrite it as
$$y'=2\left(\frac{y+2}{x+y-1}\right)^2 = 2\left(\frac{y+2}{(x-3)+(y+2)}\right)^2$$
then, let $y_1 = y+2$ and $x_1 = x-3$.

Answer (score 3):

$$y'=2\left(\frac{y+2}{x+y-1}\right)^2$$
After the change of variables $\quad\begin{cases}
y=Y-2\\
x=X+3
\end{cases}\quad$ the ODE becomes homogeneous :
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=2\left(\frac{Y}{X+Y} \right)^2$$
The usual change to solve homogeneous ODES is $\quad Y=X\:u(X)$

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=2\left(\frac{y+2}{x+y-1}\right)^2$$
$$2x'=\left(\frac{x+y-1}{y+2}\right )^2$$
$$2x'\color{red}{+2}=\left(\frac{x+y-1}{y+2}\right)^2\color{red}{+2}$$
Substitute $w=x+y-1$ and $z=y+2$:
$$2w'=\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^2+2$$
The differential equation is homogeneous then substitute $w=tz$
$$2(t'z+t)=t^2+2$$
$$2(t-1)'z=(t-1)^2+1$$
This is separable.